# Concurrency passing value type to 'Thread.Start' does not work as expected

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In my code below, the `Id` property of `ThreadClass` is not set deterministically as expected (`ThreadArray[0]'s ThreadClass.Id = 0, ThreadArray[1]'s ThreadClass.Id = 1,` etc).

If I debug and slow down the `Thread.Start()'s`, everything works as expected. But when the program runs at full-speed, I get all `Id's = 4` (or similar). I can't lock `i` because it's not a reference variable. Clearly, I am encountering a race condition. What am I doing wrong?

**Main.cs**

```
for (int i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
{
    ThreadArray[i] = new Thread(() =>
        {
            new ThreadClass(i);
        });
    ThreadArray[i].Start();
}
```

**ThreadClass.cs**

```
private int Id { get; set; }

public ThreadClass(int i) {
    Id = id;
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am thread " + i");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
I am thread 0
I am thread 1
I am thread 2
I am thread 3
... 5 second wait ...
I am thread 0
I am thread 1
I am thread 2
I am thread 3
```

**Actual output:**

```
I am thread 4
I am thread 4
I am thread 4
I am thread 4
... 5 second wait ...
I am thread 4
I am thread 4
I am thread 4
I am thread 4
```

Note that at this point each instance of `ThreadArray` is initialized to a valid `Thread` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a version of C# that doesn't close over a fresh copy of the `i` variable. By the time the threads are executed, `i` is at or near `ThreadCount`. Simply create a copy of the variable so the closure can capture that instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++) 
{  
    int temp = i;
    ThreadArray[i] = new Thread(() =>  
        {              
            new ThreadClass(temp); 
        });      
}
```

By the way, the version of C# in VS 2012 (or .NET 4.5) fixes this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh678682(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx for details

Comment: For future readers, based on Rob's blog post, .Net 4.5 will not change behavior in the case I described above. The change only affects the foreach() statement, in cases where you wish for a lambda to access a loop variable, you will still need to copy the loop variable to a local variable.

Answer (score -1):

Move your ThreadArray[i].Start() outside your for loop and simply set up all your classes before starting the threads.  Even though you will have to loop twice, it should ensure that everything occurs in the order/state that you want it to.

--EDIT Darnit got to the answer just before I did-- :)